# Attaching a library to Azure databricks cluster

Tags: azure-databricks

I want to make use of ts-flint on Azure Datatbricks. I believe the process is documented here: https://docs.azuredatabricks.net/user-guide/libraries.html

I tried to create a library from the Azure portal and attach it to my testCluster, but using the instructions provided but I can't seem to see it (Calling ts-flint in the Notbook tells me its not found).

Am I doing something wrong?

Also this is the Python file I tried to load into the library: https://pypi.org/project/ts-flint/#files

Is this .gz file not a valid PyPy file or something?

Comment: from your workspace if you right click and create a new library, then from the library page select Egg or PyPi then simply add ts-flint in the text box below. Next you'll select which cluster(s) you want it to apply to.

Comment: Yep that is precisely what I did

Comment: ok - so you can see the library itself in the workspace but when you try and use it the notebook complains that it isn't there?

Comment: Not quite - I can do everything you mentioned but then go if I go to the workspace I don't see it showing up.

Comment: hm ok - what happens after you click 'install library'

Answer (score 0):

I would try the Databricks specific version found here: https://github.com/databricks/databricks-accelerators/tree/master/projects/databricks-flint

From your "Libraries" tab for your Databricks cluster install via the upload of the jar from the repo above.